# UIImageView at a wrong location of the custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I make a custom `UITableViewCell` through storyboard, and set the `UIImageView`'s frame of `(248, 60, 52, 52)` in the size inspector. When I run the application, the `UIImageView` still at the left of the custom `UITableViewCell`. Why?

Comment: Please add code examples to back your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to auto layout. If that is turned on (which it is by default), the system will add defaults for you, if you don't add them your self. The constraints it adds are left, top, width, and height. Instead of setting the frame, you should setup the constraints that you want.